# Showing toast messages with primevue in a vue/nuxt application

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, primevue

I have a Vue application that uses nuxt. I want to show toast messages by using primevue in such a way that I can show these messages from anywhere in my application.
I also want to keep track of the notifications in a store.

What I have done so far:
Added a `primevue.ts` to my `plugins` folder that contains the following code:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true });
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ToastService);
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component("Toast", Toast); //Is this necessary
});
```

My `app.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
    <Toast />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useNotificationsStore } from '@/stores/NotificationStore';

    const notificationsStore = useNotificationsStore();
</script>
```

The NotificationsStore:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
export const useNotificationsStore = defineStore({
id: 'notifications',
state: () => ({
    messages: []
}),
actions: {
    addMessage(message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
    },
    removeMessage(index: number) {
        this.messages.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
});
```

One of the locations I want to show toastmessages from is my `useFetchApi` function which handles requests to my backend so I can show messages when it throws a BadRequest or even ServerError status:

```
import { UseFetchOptions } from "nuxt/app";
import { useNotificationsStore } from "~/stores/NotificationStore";
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

export function useFetchApi<T = any>(url:string, options:UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
const { t } = useI18n()
const { addMessage } = useNotificationsStore();

return useFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    async onResponseError({ request, response, error }) {
           
        addMessage({
            severity: 'error',
            summary: 'Error',
            detail: "TEST",
            life: 3000                
        });
    },
});
}
```

What would be the best place to actually show the toast message and how exactly would I do that?
I have been reading the documentation and tried different things but the messages don't show up in the browser.

Comment: Did you ever try `vue-toastification` library for toast notification?